# three.js spotlight.map TextureLoader not supported anymore?

Tags: javascript, three.js, light

I am trying to make a projection mapping on to 3d objects. I have found this source to do so:
https://rawgit.com/mbredif/three.js/demo_spotColorMap/docs/#api/lights/SpotLight
This example even shows a video.

Now I re did this entire project, but the image mapping does not work. I am using

```
spotLight.map = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('textures/sky.jpg');
```

Here is my example: https://eriksachse.com/projection/

No error in the console, so the .map function should be access able? Or does this function no more exist in r100?

Comment: Ok, I have used the same version as the example on GitHub, and its working! But why is that so?

Comment: To me this is a useful tool